# Enable removed function in C++17

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

My main code is written with C++17. Now I want to integrate a external library which is written against C++14.

Since the library header using some functions such as `std::binary_function`, `std::random_shuffle` which are removed in C++17, I cannot use this library.

Is it possible to re-enable removed functions in C++17?
I am using MSVC 2017 and solution for MSVC only is totally acceptable.

Comment: When you say that your main code is written in C++17, do you mean that it relies on features that were new in C++17?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes. My code depends on C++17 features and libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC` to 1 before including any standard header.

From https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c17-feature-removals-and-deprecations/:

> - N4190 “Removing auto_ptr, random_shuffle(), And Old <functional> Stuff”
>
> Implemented in VS 2017 15.3 (and earlier). Restored by defining
>   _HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC to 1